# How to import generic Binary Search Tree in Java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I need to use the generic Binary Search Tree, not the implementation. For example, when I use LinkedLists I just use the generic implementation of Java. I do this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

How can I do the same thing but for trees?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to define a class with generics, you might want to look at [this piece of documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

If you're referring to using interfaces instead of concrete implementations, you probably want

```
List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

where `List` is the interface and `LinkedList` is an actual class that implements it. You can define an interface that your binary search tree implements e.g.

```
interface Tree<K,V>{
    V get(K key);
}
```

Comment: All i need to do is add values to a tree without implement the tree in my code... How can i do that?

Comment: You can just use `TreeMap` or `TreeSet`. They are implemented using binary search trees.

Answer (score 0):

From [Collection Framework Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html), there are two balanced tree classes you can use

- [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)
- [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)